# Android - Scene Transition animation on the map marker click?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have seen this your demo, But can I achieve this Scene Transition animation on the map marker. Please see, the map image with the marker (**Yeats**), ***I want to perform shared Transition animation on the maker click***, We are using below code in Scene Transition animation.
I have seen this example,
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActivitySceneTransitionBasic

```
ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation();
```

this method takes **sharedElement (view), but in the case of google map marker, we can not send Marker object in this method**.
anyone guide me how can I perform shared Transition on map marker click.
[image]

Comment: you cannot do that using `Scene`s / `Transition`s - they do not work with remote views

Comment: @pskink, thanks for your reply, any other way to perform this animation on marker click

Comment: https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/workcation-app-part-2-animating-markers-with-mapoverlaylayout/ or https://codinginfinite.com/android-example-animate-marker-map-current-location/

Comment: @pskink, thanks for your suggestion, it looks tough with the marker. but i will try